# How to write custom object to database when app crashes?

Tags: android, database, crash

I have an app I'm developing where I create a custom object with 200+ fields. I want to write it to a table in my database only when the app crashes. I tried putting code in the onDestroy() method of my activity but that is always called, not just when the app crashes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)
        {
            // Insert your code here
        }
    });
```

I found this nice little piece of code and it works perfectly. Just put this in an activity and it will catch anything that you don't have a try-catch for. Just put whatever code you want inside and it will run it if the app crashes. Hope this helps someone.